# how to create a nested grid in ngtable?

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid, ngtable

I am trying to create a nested grid in my ngtable like this:

```
 <table ng-table="tableParams" class="table">
      <tr ng-repeat="user in $data">
        <td data-title="'Name'">{{user.name}}</td>
        <td data-title="'Age'">{{user.age}}</td>
        <td data-title="'kids'">
          <table ng-table="nestedtableParams" class="table">
            <tr ng-repeat="nesteduser in $nesteddata">
              <td data-title="'Name'">{{nesteduser.name}}</td>
              <td data-title="'Age'">{{nesteduser.age}}</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

question is: why is the nested data not displaying? here is a plunkr:
http://plnkr.co/edit/dKTtU89f7z6nQptgEZxN?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

Got this working by adding the data to the `$scope`: (partial example code)

```
$scope.nesteddata = [{
    name: "Kid Moroni",
    age: 50
}, {
    name: "Kid Tiancum",
    age: 43
}, {
    name: "Kid Jacob",
    age: 27
}, {
    name: "Kid Nephi",
    age: 29
}, {
    name: "Kid Enos",
    age: 34
}];
```

And then, in the controller functions, refer to these `$scope` variables:

```
$scope.nestedtableParams = new ngTableParams({
    page: 1, // show first page
    count: 10 // count per page
}, {
    total: $scope.nesteddata.length, // length of data
    getData: function($defer, params) {
        $defer.resolve($scope.nesteddata.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
    }
});
```

Finally in the markup I left out the `$ prefix`, since this data is now in the scope:

```
<table ng-table="tableParams" class="table">
    <tr ng-repeat="user in data">
        <td data-title="'Name'">{{user.name}}</td>
        <td data-title="'Age'">{{user.age}}</td>
        <td>
            <table ng-table="nestedtableParams" class="table">
                <tr ng-repeat="user in nesteddata">
                    <td data-title="'Name'">{{user.name}}</td>
                    <td data-title="'Age'">{{user.age}}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[Working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/yRGMrZayakNIuOMTNtlB?p=preview) (Although I doubt that it makes sense to nest grids like this)

Comment: the plunker is broken